# Can't render shadows the way I want

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers, layers

I'm setting up render layers and I am stuck on something I know is really silly. I just want to render a background plane where 2 objects casts shadows to.

My goal is to have 3 different image sequences as follows:

1. The background color
2. Object 1's shadow on the background
3. Object 2's shadow on the background

Simple huh?
Well... in the background color layer I have unchecked Object 1 and 2 collections so they are not rendered. I have also unchecked Shadow Catcher for the background plane geometry (If it's ON, the render I get is blank)

The problem is having Shadow Catcher off makes the other 2 layers to cast a shadow + they render the background color too.

I know it's not a bug, this is just my ignorance on how to correctly set up layers for this case in particular.

Can I get some help?

Oh, and since we are here, all of my other layers are correctly rendered. How can I render again (once this problem is sorted), but tell Blender to skip the layers I am happy with?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: if you provide a blend file, we can check it, which helps a lot

Comment: I am sorry, I can't submit my blender file due to nda
I thought the description of the problem would suffice, specially when I explain what my goal is